# Store hashed email in the dictionary .Net

Tags: c#, .net, hash, hashcode

For an application purpose, I want to store an complete content of the email (string) in the dictionary.
[I know that this is what every hash function provides but wanted to explicitly state that the hash for the same string should always be the same]

Since its not for cryptographic reason and only for storing in dictionary. Can any one please suggest a good hashing function that is available in .Net. My concern is that the email string can be pretty big and i want my hash function to support the big string and not cause frequent collision. I am looking for storing around 500 entries.

Please note i dont want to write my own hash funciton but leverage an existing availaible hash function in .Net

Comment: @EdneyHolder: OP ask for C#, your question is for Java.

Comment: Why not just use sha1?

Comment: What's wrong with `string.GetHashCode()` ? Why do you believe that built in function is *so bad* that it will cause multiple collision between 500 entries?

Comment: I am worried about long strings. Hence the concern.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider to use [HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_ComputeHash_System_Byte___).

Here is an example which is provided with this function:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string source = "Hello World!";
        using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            string hash = GetHash(sha256Hash, source);    
            Console.WriteLine($"The SHA256 hash of {source} is: {hash}.");    
            Console.WriteLine("Verifying the hash...");    
            if (VerifyHash(sha256Hash, source, hash))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The hashes are the same.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The hashes are not same.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, string input)
    {    
        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));    
        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();    
        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }    
        // Return the hexadecimal string.
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    // Verify a hash against a string.
    private static bool VerifyHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, string input, string hash)
    {
        // Hash the input.
        var hashOfInput = GetHash(hashAlgorithm, input);    
        // Create a StringComparer an compare the hashes.
        StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;    
        return comparer.Compare(hashOfInput, hash) == 0;
    }    
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I don't see how this can help: OP's main concern seem to be performance of hash function - your suggestion is even worse that built in `string.GetHashCode` as it copies string to byte array first and than uses much slower SHA256... Plus the result of your code does not math `Dictionary` expectation of `int`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's not true, his concern is not a performance, but **collision** He says `My concern is that the email string can be pretty big and i want my hash function to support the big string and not cause frequent collision.`, so `string.GetHashCode` is a **bad choice** for him. SHA256 could be an overkill for him, but I'm not forcing him to use it ... it's just an example - he is free to use whatever he wants from `HashAlgorithm ` 